# How to set styleUrls to css file from another folder?

Tags: css, angular, styles

I have component `src/app/admin/create-company/create-company.component.ts`
and css file `src/app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css`

How can I use this css in `styleUrls` of `create-company.component.ts`

Things I have already tried:

```
src/app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css
./src/app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css
../src/app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css

app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css
./app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css
../app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css
```

etc

Also I have tried direct folder: `/Users/Vladimir/Workspaces/Project/coupon-system-client/src/app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css`

Comment: Try this "../shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css"

Comment: @Thiagz I apologise for the fact that I didn't write what I already tried. I'll fix it now. This one doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its a relative path. So you have to backtrack to the first shared folder with the other directory.

If you want to access `admin.component.css` from `create-company.component.ts` - This should be the relative path:

```
../../../shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css
```

The first shared folder is the `app` folder, which you are accessing like this:

```
../../../
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked with adding app:
../../../app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css

Answer (score 1):

Since your desired css to be referred is present in different folder all together, you have to navigate to that folder using `../`. First navigate to `app` folder using `../../../` then navigate further.

```
../../../shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked with adding app:
../../../app/shared/layouts/admin/admin.component.css